# How to request that spotlight indexes one specific folder only using a command line?

Tags: time-machine, spotlight

**Context**

I cannot seem to be able to get TimeMachine to backup my HD, because a given 
directory seems to contain corrupted files so that I get this kind of message in the Console:

> com.apple.backupd: Indexing a file failed. Returned 1 for: /Users/JohnDoe/This.Folder/this.file

**Question**

How to request that spotlight indexes one specific folder only?

---

My purpose is to identify in one shot all the defective files

Ideally I would prefer that the indexing be temporarily and quick (I.e it should not impact the default index) since my purpose is to identify defective files.

Comment: Follow the steps in [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/237498/88313).  It will tell you how to add & remove locations from Spotlight's index.  See if it helps and post back.

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking at a command line to index only temporarily one given directory.

Comment: You should probably update your question to state that you're looking for a temporary solution using command line only.  The question doesn't indicate that.  It will help prevent you from receiving answers that don't meet your needs.

Comment: You are right. Will do

Comment: Have you tried using `mdimport /path/to/target/folder`?

Comment: @user3439894 yes and I get an error `(Error) ImportPluginLoading: Couldn't load plugin 'Spotlight/LyX-Metadata.mdimporter/ -- file://localhost/Applications/LyX.app/Contents/Library/'`